# Additional Filtering On One Statement In WHERE Clause

Tags: sql

I have large table with many columns, specifically three that I need to work with:  CaseGroup, CaseStatus, and CaseDesc. I am trying to pull data based on open CaseStatus, multiple CaseGroups, and then on one casegroup only the littering CaseDesc. Here is the easy part I already have:

```
Select  CaseID, CaseStatus, CaseGroup, CaseDesc
FROM  CodeEnforcement
WHERE  CaseStatus = 'Open' AND CaseGroup IN ('ProStd', 'San', 'Tow', 'Weeds')
```

I want all CaseDesc for ProStd, Tow, and Weeds. However, for San I only want `LIKE '%littering%'`. How do I go about accomplishing that? Do I have to join two select statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
Select  CaseID, CaseStatus, CaseGroup, CaseDesc
FROM  CodeEnforcement
WHERE  CaseStatus = 'Open' AND 
       (CaseGroup IN ('ProStd', 'Tow', 'Weeds') OR
        (CaseGroup = 'San' AND CaseDesc LIKE '%littering%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `or` to your conditions. Something like this.

```
Select  CaseID, CaseStatus, CaseGroup, CaseDesc
FROM  CodeEnforcement
WHERE  CaseStatus = 'Open' AND (CaseGroup IN ('ProStd', 'Tow', 'Weeds')
or (CaseGroup = 'San'and CaseDesc like '%littering%')) --make sure you use parentheses
```